# FCFS algorithm for linux kernel process scheduler

Tags: linux, process, kernel, scheduler

In linux kenel process scheduler there is a priority type SCHED_FIFO. I want to change the scheduling policy.
I have two questions:

1- Where, in the kernel source code, is it mentioned that after a tick the cpu should belong to the interrupted process(Because in FIFO the process should remain until it finishes)?

2- In SCHED_RR where the interrupted process is inserted at the end of the waiting queue again?

I use 2.6.31 kernel

Thank you.

Comment: This should not give you the answer but it's a nice website to take a look at: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/

Comment: Thank you but I did not find my answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that scheduler_tick function calls appropriate function of each class and inside it the appropriate function for reinserting the process (enqueue for Real-time) is called.

Answer (score 1):

Read the function `do_sched_rt_period_timer` in `kernel/sched_rt.c` about line 530.